# Has Win10 1903 upgrade destroyed my system partition?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

tl;dr. Yes, Windows 1903 update destroyed my system partition. Thanks, Microsoft.

After failed 1903 upgrade (from current Win10 1803 installation), my computer won't boot, says Boot Manager Missing. All standard solutions fail (I won't bother listing them at this point). I have a vhdx system image on a second drive but only get failure when attempting to restore. In WinRE command prompt, `chkdsk` reports no problems, `bootrec.exe /scanos` reports it can't find an operating system, `bootrec /fixmbr` says access denied, and `diskpart list vol` says that my system partition has format RAW. This seems bad, but maybe there's still a way to recover? Or is my system partition totally unrecoverable (such that I just need to do a bare metal windows install and then hope that my system image will restore on it?

In this output of `diskpart list vol` you can see Vol 2 (111GB) which is my system partition (on an SSD, if that matters), Vol 3 is a second data-only hard drive, Vol 4 is the USB stick that I used to boot WinRE.

[image: LIST VOL output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look good!

Right now, I'd say that `bootrec.exe /scanos` fails because, according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues):

> /ScanOs This option scans all disks for installations that are
>   compatible with Windows Vista or Windows 7. It also displays the
>   entries that are currently not in the BCD store. Use this option when
>   there are Windows Vista or Windows 7 installations that the Boot
>   Manager menu does not list.

(I know this documentation says Windows 7 or Vista, but [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/bootrec/) shows that bootrec is part of Windows 10, so I'm not too worried about the differences.)

Since your installation partition is now showing up as RAW, I would say that bootrec doesn't work because the partition isn't in a format that bootrec can read.

My first step would be to backup the whole drive, bit for bit, using a linux live cd (like Ubuntu, but anything would work, really) and the utility [dd](https://www.linux.com/learn/full-metal-backup-using-dd-command). Be *REALLY* careful using dd, as you can just as easily erase everything on the drive as you can make a backup.

(Another option would be a tool like [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), in case you don't want to risk it with dd.)

Then, with a backup in place, I would try to use a utility to recover the NTFS partition. [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is one that I would probably try, but I'm sure there are many options.

After that, I would try bootrec.exe /scanos again see if the normal Microsoft tools can got you back up and running.

Comment: Ooh, TestDisk sounds promising, I don't think I've seen that before. But the only place I have to backup to is the second hard drive in the computer, which is also where my vhdx system image backup is. Having zero experience using dd, is there a risk that I'd overwrite files on that drive?

Comment: Yes, there is a risk. If you specify the output path incorrectly, you can easily end up trashing all the data on one or both drives. dd has no intelligence - it's basically copying data from one path to another, blindly. It may be better to find another bit-for-bit backup solution... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: gddrescue has a slightly nicer syntax and is kinda designed for data recovery

Comment: Well, I got in over my head with TestDisk; system partition ended up totally unreadable. I ended up wiping the drive, clean-installing windows, and attempting to restore my vhdx backup ... which failed! I'm able to mount the vhdx though, so am reduced to copying all my old files and such from it to the new installation. Lot of wasted time but I don't think I'll lose anything. Other than my last shred of respect and patience with Microsoft. Thanks for trying to help, EchoLynx; I appreciate it!

Comment: @mc510 I'm sorry that it didn't work out, though I'm glad you had backups! If there's anything in particular that you think I should update in my answer, please let me know and I will. I don't want someone coming back to this question and running into trouble.

Comment: @EchoLynx, your info was super helpful; my problem was a combination of insufficient understanding of Windows system partition structure and (I think) severely corrupted disk. I don’t even know if any other info would have been helpful to me!